# How do I create an object with its type defined conditionally?

Tags: c#, class, entity

I have a series of classes each having different properties and each of them having an ID (per-type not per-instance).

Given the following:

```
public class TestEntity : EntityBase {
    public override ushort ID { get; } = 1;
    public override void something() { do_something(); }
}
public class OtherEntity : EntityBase {
    public override ushort ID { get; } = 2;
    public override void something() { something_else(); }
}
```

When reading data I only have a `ushort`:

```
ushort EntityId = BitConverter.ToUInt16(data.GetRange(CURRENT_POSITION + TILE_ENTITY_ID_OFFSET, TILE_ENTITY_ID_LENGTH).ToArray().Reverse().ToArray(), 0);
```

How do I use the value of `EntityId` to create different type of objects based on its value? Using `if` or `switch` statements is not an option as there will be more than 200 types.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

Comment: @Matthew with the factory pattern, the caller knows what they want instantiated. As you can see in the C# code example, the factory still needs a switch.

Comment: That's one way to do a factory.  There are lots of others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way would be to define an Attribute-Subclass containing an ID property and then to annotate all types with the attribute providing a unique id for each type.
Layter you can collect and filter loaded types containing given attribute and filter by the ID property of the attribute.
With this approach you could later add additional subtypes without the need to modify the consuming code.
The implementation could look like:

```
public sealed class MyCustomAttribute : Attribute
{
    public ushort Id { get; set; }

    public MyCustomAttribute(ushort id)
    {
        this.Id = id;
    }
}

public class MyDemoConsumer
{
    public void MyConsumingMethod(ushort requiredTypeId)
    {
        var requestedType = AppDomain
            .CurrentDomain
            .GetAssemblies()
            .SelectMany(asm => asm.GetTypes())
            .Where(type => type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyCustomAttribute), false).Any())
            .Select(type => new { Type = type, CustomId = type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyCustomAttribute), false).Cast<MyCustomAttribute>().Single().Id })
            .Where(item => item.CustomId == requiredTypeId)
            .Select(item => item.Type)
            .SingleOrDefault();

        if (requestedType != null)
        {
            var result = Activator.CreateInstance(requestedType);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: With 200+ types, this is probably how I would do it.

Comment: @MichaelGunter you can never know with how many types you have to deal in the future :)

Comment: Personally if I had over 200 types already declared I'd find a new pattern.  That sounds like a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: @MatthewWhited the very first requirement for search for new pattern is the understanding that something is going wrong, which is not always present by affected persons

Answer (score 8):

If I understand your question, here's one way to go about it (there are many).

```
private static Dictionary<ushort, Type> TypeMap = new Dictionary<ushort, Type>()
                                                   {
                                                       { 1, typeof(TestEntity) },
                                                       { 2, typeof(OtherEntity) }
                                                   };

private EntityBase CreateEntity(ushort id)
{
    var type = TypeMap[id];
    return (EntityBase) Activator.CreateInstance(type);
}
```

Comment: I wrote the exact same thing... damn your quick fingers! +1

Comment: @MichaelGunter very nice approach (+1) from me !

Answer (score 3):

... tons of ways of doing this but here's a simple one ...

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var simpleFactory = new SimpleFactory();
        var entity = simpleFactory.Create(1);
        entity.Something();
    }
}

public abstract class EntityBase
{
    public abstract ushort ID { get; }
    public abstract void Something();
}

public class TestEntity : EntityBase
{
    public override ushort ID { get { return 1; } }
    public override void something() { }
}
public class OtherEntity : EntityBase
{
    public override ushort ID { get { return 2; } }
    public override void something() { }
}

public class SimpleFactory
{
    private Dictionary<ushort, Func<EntityBase>> config = new Dictionary<ushort, Func<EntityBase>>
    {
        { 1, ()=>new TestEntity()},
        { 2, ()=>new OtherEntity()},
    };

    public EntityBase Create(ushort entityId)
    {
        if (!config.ContainsKey(entityId))
            throw new InvalidOperationException();

        return config[entityId]();
    }
}
```

Comment: You get my +1 for using lambdas to avoid reflection.

Comment: I like this pattern because it also makes it easy to provide parameters to the constructors where I would otherwise be unable to do so... such as `T Create<T>() where T class, new() {...}`